# Apple TV 3rd generation

Tags: appletv

I bought an Apple TV but the remote didn’t come with it (used). I was told I could just use the Apple TV remote app on my phone. So I powered up Apple TV , connected it to router with Ethernet cable so it's on the same network as my iPhone. On the Apple TV remote app - it connects but wants a 4 digit code to be entered on the Apple TV. I can't do that with no remote and the Apple remote app gives no other options!!! How do I enter that code without the actual remote?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way out of this conundrum, assuming you have a bluetooth keyboard? It doesn't have to be an Apple bluetooth keyboard, any bluetooth keyboard should work.

Follow these steps:

1. Disconnect the keyboard from the device it's currently being used with and switch it off
2. Switch on the Apple TV
3. Switch on the keyboard
4. Your Apple TV should recognise the keyboard and prompt you with a code
5. Enter the code using the keyboard
6. Once the keyboard is paired, you can use it to navigate through the Settings and add your Apple Remote app
7. Once connected and everything is okay, switch off your keyboard and reconnect it to its original device

Let me know if you run into any problems.